# Dropping the closed requirement from the symplectic manifold definition?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

A **symplectic manifold** is a pair $(M,\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a non-degenerate closed two-form. When $M$ is compact, Hodge decomposition implies that such manifolds have non-zero second betti-number, and one sometimes analogues of the Hard Lefschetz Theorem.

What happens if one drops the assumption that $\omega$ is closed. For sure $\omega$ will not give a class, but maybe something interesting will happen. What are examples of such spaces.

Comment: If $\omega$ s not closed it will not give a class at all —zero or not.

Comment: If $\omega$ is not closed, you get what is called an almost symplectic manifold. The structure is then simply a reduction of structure group (from $GL_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ to the symplectic group) for the tangent bundle of the manifold. Essentially, this is more homotopy theory than geometry...

Comment: @ Mariano - Yes of course, thanks for pointing the stupid error. I have edited it now.

Comment: While it's true that the condition of _admitting_ such a reduction is topology, once you have one the situation is _more_ geometrical: when $\omega$ is closed there is no local structure but now there is, namely $d\omega$ itself. These geometries can be classified into four types.

Comment: Two more comments, concerning examples: the only spheres admitting an almost symplectic structure are $S^2$ and $S^6$, with $S^2$ being symplectic and $S^6$ not. Moreover, an application of the $h$-principle methods show that almost symplectic structures on open manifolds are homotopic (through almost symplectic structures) to symplectic structures, this is known as flexibility.

Comment: @PaulReynolds Can you give a reference for the classification you mentioned, please?

Comment: @OldřichSpáčil, I believe it's in Gray and Hervella's _The sixteen classes of almost Hermitian manifolds and their linear invariants (1980)_, but I can't seem to find the paper in my collection (and I don't belong to an institution). You get a finer classification when you have the full almost-Hermitian structure, which is the main part of the paper. The idea is to decompose $\Lambda^3V$ into irreducible reps of the non-compact symplectic group, and apply that to $d\omega$. Similar classifications exist for various other structures, and there are subsequent papers.

Comment: @PaulReynolds Thank you very much for both the reference and the idea!